# Script input data run commands based off it

Tags: linux, text-processing, scripting, zsh

Not sure where to begin I only know basic text processing.

I am trying to create a script that will search for zfs snapshots based off a VM name (given as a command parametet) and then select the newest snapshot and finally transfer it to another server.

For example I will run

```
script.sh 2839
```

Which will first run

```
zfs list -t snapshot | grep "vm-2839"
```

find the following files, and select the newest one based off the date

```
zfs/backups/vm-2839-disk-0@ZAP_home1_2023-01-20T21:53:29p0000--1d      193M      -     11.9G  -
zfs/backups/vm-2839-disk-0@ZAP_home1_2023-01-22T11:54:19p0000--1d     18.2M      -     11.9G  -
zfs/backups/vm-2839-disk-0@ZAP_home1_2023-01-22T16:08:20p0000--1d        0B      -     11.9G  -
```

It should then finally send that file to an external server

```
zfs send zfs/backups/vm-2839-disk-0@ZAP_home1_2023-01-22T16:08:20p0000--1d | ssh root@10.0.10.200 "zfs receive zfs/vm-2839-disk-0"
```

Comment: I wondered a lot about what snapshots you're referring to until I saw your `zfs …` command line :D Added that tage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, the date format you're using is numerically sortable.

So the approach to this is

- Tell `zfs list` to not output data you don't care about
- Tell `zfs list` to sort according to the date of creation
- take the first line of output and roll with it

So, I don't have zfs set up on the machine I'm sitting in front of right now, so I'm just going of the [official documentation](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zfs-list.8.html) – as you should have!

```bash
#!/bin/bash

machine=$1 # save the first passed argument in the variable "machine"

zfs list -o name -s creation -t snapshot | grep "vm-${machine}" |tail -n1 | xargs zfs send | ssh root@10.0.10.200 "zfs receive zfs/vm-${machine}-disk-0"

#         ^------------------------------ specify the field(s) to display;
#                ^                        "name" is the first mentioned on the
#                |                        man page.
#                |
#                \----------------------- specify which field to sort by. As
#                                         linked to, zfsprops man page tells
#                                         that "creation" is the time the
#                                         snapshot was created
#
#                                                             ^---- pipe to "tail", which
#                                                                   ^---- keeps the last 1 line(s)
#
#                                                                        ^---- pipe to xargs, which
#                                                                              takes the input and
#                                                                              appends it as argument
#                                                                              to the passed command
#                                                                              "zfs send"
#          
#                                                                                      ^---- pipe to
#                                                                                            your ssh
#                                                                                            as before
```

Comment: 2839 is not the only virtual machine. If I have 10 virtual machines that wont work (2839 is the virtual machine ID)

Comment: hope the edit helps

Comment: Thanks works well. Maybe a silly question but if I have two SSH sessions running and I do this command in each window will the machine=$1 conflict? As it takes a while to move data

Comment: No it won't conflict. $1 is the first Argument passed to *each* execution of the script. The different executions are fully independent and isolated

Comment: I have one issue with this if a virtual machine has the ID 100 but another has ID 1000 it will conflict as they both contain "100" can can we adjust the command to require the VM ID to be exactly 100?

Comment: how about adding a `-` after `vm-${machine}`? (I'm not trying to be petty here, but I think you'd exceed the threshold of "getting help" towards "getting someone else to even do your attempting to solve the problem" if I modified this script even further for you.)